# Airflow scheduler not pick up tasks, task waiting forever

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I met an issue that my task in a tag never got pick up by workers for some reason.
When I look at the task details:

> All dependencies are met but the task instance is not running. In most
>   cases this just means that the task will probably be scheduled soon
>   unless:
>   - The scheduler is down or under heavy load
>
> If this task instance does not start soon please contact your Airflow
>   administrator for assistance.

I checked the  scheduler, no errors in the log, also restarted it a few times.

I also checked the airflow websever log, only notice this:

> 22/11/2018 12:10:39[2018-11-22 01:10:39,747] {{cli.py:644}} DEBUG - [5
>   / 5] killing 1 workers 22/11/2018 12:10:39[2018-11-22 01:10:39 +0000]
>   [43] [INFO] Handling signal: ttou 22/11/2018 12:10:39[2018-11-22
>   01:10:39 +0000] [348] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 348)

Not sure what happens, it worked fine before.

Airflow version 1.9.0, never change the version, only playing around some of the config: `min_file_process_interval` and `dag_dir_list_interval` (but I put it back to default when encounter this issue)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I do notice that this happens when I am playing around with some of the airflow config and rebuild our docker airflow image, then I revert it back to the original version, which used to work. Then the problem solved.

I also notice one error occurred (but not always captured) in my celery workers when I use the newly built image:

> Unrecoverable error: AttributeError("'float' object has no attribute 'items'",)

So find that it is related to the latest redis release (Celery will use redis), you can find [more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53322425/celery-critical-mainprocess-unrecoverable-error-attributeerrorfloat-object/53324691#53324691).